# JQuery store persistent data

Tags: jquery

I am writing a program, and you enter data, which is then graphically displayed on the screen. What i would like to do is to be able to save the data, so the program can start next time and  display the same data, so you do not have to re-enter it.

The structure of the information looks like this:

main div

--data 1(class, id, and the text in between the tags)

--data 2(same as above)

--etc...

Is there a good way to store this data and recover it in a later session?

Comment: Yes there is. What have you tried? Are you intending to do this solely with jQuery?

Comment: Yes, you can save the data temporary via ajax and next time, you fetch the data via ajax to display it. Another solution would be to use HTML5 Web database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some examples:

- [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage)
- [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage)
- [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie)

Comment: Got cookies to work when i hosted them on a private server. I think i will stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Oriol you can use Storage object, it can be session or local. I have used sessionStorage and it is working fine,

You could use,

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
let data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('key');

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```

Thanks!!